# How to press buttons in a dialog window from terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal, dialog

[image: WHAT TO DO!?]

I don't get what to do! How do I press `<Ok>`? I clicked on it, typed `Ok`, pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>, everything!